# Unrecognized token error while trying to manually copy an sqlite row

Tags: python, database, sqlite, row, token

Having some trouble dumping some values in SQLite that I can't quite figure out as I have successfully implemented the same structure elsewhere in my code. Basically I am passing a list of column names and values to update a database using the structure below:

```
def add_data(conn, primary_key, *args: tuple):

    conn.set_trace_callback(print)

    
    # --- Separate columns and values ---
    columns = []
    values = []
    for arg in args:
        columns.append(arg[0])
        values.append(arg[1])
        
    columns.append('timestamp')
    values.append(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    
    # --- Read the SQL Dataframe ---
    df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM projtable ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;", conn)
    latest_ID = list(df['ID'][-1:])[0]


    # --- Primary Key Does Not Exist:  make a new row ---
    if primary_key == None:
        columns.append('ID')
        values.append(latest_ID + 1)
        exec_text = 'INSERT INTO projtable (' + ','.join(columns) +') values(' + ','.join(['?'] * len(values)) + ')'
        conn.execute(exec_text, values)
        
    
    # --- Primary Key Exists:  update an existing row ---
    else:
    
        exec_text = 'UPDATE projtable SET '
        for col, val in zip(columns, values):
            exec_text += f"`{col}` = ?, "
        exec_text = exec_text[:-2]
        exec_text += f' WHERE ID = {int(primary_key)}'
        conn.execute(exec_text, values)
        
    # --- Commit and Kill ---
    conn.commit()
    
    return 'success'


def add_column(conn, column_name, column_type, default):

    exec_text = f'ALTER TABLE projtable ADD COLUMN {column_name} {column_type} DEFAULT {default}'
    conn.execute(exec_text)
    
    conn.commit()
    
    return 'success'
```

I am passing a large list of values to be updated in this database with the primary_key variable set to None to create a new row using the format below which has worked fine until now:

```
        status = add_data(
            conn,
            primary_key,
            ('column name 1', value1),
            ('column name 2', value2),
            .
            .
            .
            ('column name x', valuex))
```

When running the code for a pretty long list I am getting an error for an unrecognized token error on the last line of the list referring to an earlier token - the specific line is shown below:

```
            ('1_aux_loss', 0.1),
```

I have seen other issues with column names beginning with a number but the exact same structure has worked fine in other code sections without issues (I update that same parameter in the same way in another section of code). The only thing I can think of is that the list I am passing is longer here but I am stumped as to what is causing this error. Basically I am trying to take an existing row in sqlite database and copy some key variables (~80) to a new row.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].